# Grammar Corrections

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, orthography

Correcting Grammar:

"The committee is not only working to preserve historical buildings, but also is interested in developing a local museum"

My Notes:
I was thinking that it violates parallelism when using "working" vs "interested"?

Also, the first part uses "to preserve" vs "in developing". Not sure if I should change those, so they both use the same structure.

I added the comma before "but" because commas go with independent clauses and *and, but, etc.*

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the original.

Comment: None of these criticisms are valid. Parallelism is not a rule of grammar, but a process of style, and it doesn't depend on identical morphology in any event. It certainly can't be "violated". And commas go wherever they're heard; their placement has nothing to do with grammar in English.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply say

> The committee is not only working to preserve historical buildings, but is also interested in developing a local museum.

It looks fine to me.

> X is ***not only doing*** something ***but is also interested in doing*** something else.

As Cascabel said in the comment, I changed ***also is*** to ***is also***, because unless you want to emphasise something, adverbs are often used between the auxiliary and the verb. ***but also is interested*** would emphasise more the clause it introduces.

Comment: The OP had "also is", but you have here "is also". Perhaps you might want to elaborate on that difference...